# Symfony 2 - htmlentities and data-prototype attribute

Tags: php, symfony

I'm making a form in Symfony 2. In my buildForm function I have the **prototype option** equal true to generate the html code for making dynamic collections. The code looks like this:

```
$builder
->add('items', 'collection' ,array(
        'type' => $this->itemType,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
    )
);
```

Before I update the vendors this array key made the **html snippet** code with htmlentities, and now the code comes with "", so that becomes an error.

**Before**

```
data-prototype="&lt;div&gt;&lt;label class=&quot;   required&quot;&gt;$$name$$&lt;/label&gt;&lt;div...
```

**Now**

```
data-prototype="<div><label class=" required">$$name$$</label><div     id="apoyoCollection_items_$$name$$"><div><label...
```

Does anyone has any idea how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem.

Someone, in the project, changed the Twig configuration to iso8559-1 in **config.yml**, like this:

```
twig: 
    charset: ISO-8859-15
```